# Mysql merge 1 table into a 2nd and count columns together

Tags: mysql, merge, sum

```
           TABLE1       
|  ID    |  NAME   |   MONEY  |  POINTS |
|  1     |  Tim    |    200   |    1    |
|  2     |  Arne   |    500   |    2    |
|  3     |  Lies   |    600   |    3    |


           TABLE2       
|  ID    |  NAME   |   MONEY  |  POINTS |
|  1     |  Tim    |    1000  |    1    |
|  2     |  Arne   |    0     |    1    |
|  3     |  Gerard |    50    |    1    |
```

This is what i need to get by merging them, the sum of the column money and points like in the next table:

```
           TABLE3      
|  ID    |  NAME   |   MONEY  |  POINTS |
|  1     |  Tim    |    1200  |    2    |
|  2     |  Arne   |    500   |    3    |
|  3     |  Lies   |    600   |    3    |
|  4     |  Gerard |    50    |    1    |
```

Its kinda hard to find how to do this with a mysql query command.
Any help would be welcome :)

Comment: what is relation between 2 tables?

Answer (score 2):

Use a UNION to combine both original tables into one table, and then use SUM aggregation to generate the totals for each row.

```
INSERT INTO table3 (name, money, points)
SELECT name, SUM(money), SUM(points)
FROM (SELECT name, money, points FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT name, money, points FROM table2) x
GROUP BY name
```

This essentially implements a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of the two tables, a feature that MySQL lacks.

Comment: +1 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/271fe/1

Comment: Way more explicit than my solution :)